# docker-compose: "no module named app" despite app.py existing in app directory

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm building a simple Flask webapp. It works on the development server without a problem, but when I try to build it into a docker container I get this error in the console:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

My basic folder structure is like this:

````
appdir/
    app.py
    dockerfile
    docker-compose
    sqlite-db/
        app.db

Here's my dockerfile:


```bash
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install gunicorn3 -y

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

WORKDIR /python-docker

CMD ["gunicorn3", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app.py", "--workers=5"]
````

And here's my docker-compose:

```bash
version: "3.8"

services:
  anonymous-flaskapp:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./sqlite-db/app.db:/app/sqlite-db
```

I've tried adding and removing

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

from the `app.py` file, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are copying the current directory (ie `appdir`) in the root of container (`COPY . .`), but after that you change the working directory `WORKDIR /python-docker` to something that there is not. So, the `app.py` does not exists in there.

One solution is to copy the source into a named directory:

```
COPY . /python-docker/
WORKDIR /python-docker/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is really helpful. Is it best practice to use a different working directory in the docker container rather than the current/"normal" working directory?

Comment: The initial working directory in the Dockerfile would be the root, `/` in the container. Depending on how you create the image, there might be different folders and/or files inside `/`, so would be best to create a named folder to contain your project.

Comment: Great. So that part seems to be working. But now I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' error when running my docker-compose on the updated dockerfile. Is there something wrong with this flow that would mess up the python package location?

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y

WORKDIR /app-docker/

COPY requirements.txt /app-docker/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /anonymous-button-docker/

Comment: After `WORKDIR /app-docker/`, you need `COPY requirements.txt /app-docker/requirements.txt`. Depends what is on requirements.txt file. Is there flask?
Try to run `docker compose run anonymous-flaskapp bash` to get a bash shell inside your container and do a `pip3 list` to see if every package is installed correctly. Try to start gunicorn there to see if it is working. Is it using the system python3? Is it configured properly? There are endless possibilities.

Comment: @chrisware from what I see from other Flask projects, they are not installing `gunicorn` via the `apt-get install` command, but rather is in the `requirements.txt` file. Try that.

Comment: So, running `docker compose run anonymous-flaskapp bash` and then `pip3 list` shows all the required dependencies, including `Flask`. However, when I exit the shell and then run `docker compose up`, I get the same `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`. Do you think it's something to do with the capitalization of `f`? That seems too simple. I will try the `gunicorn` suggestion next.